# Copying NSDictionary to NSMutable Dictionary doesn't work?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to copy the contents of one NSDictionary into a NSMutableDictionary.
This is what I have done so far.

```
 @implementation RosterListController
- (void)newMessageReceived:(NSDictionary *)messageContent 
{
   self.messageDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:messageContent];         // This is where I am copying  

   UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
   {
       UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
       if (localNotif)
      {
        localNotif.alertAction = @"OK";
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
        [app presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];

      }
    }
}
```

Then I handle this notification in appDelegate by showing a AlertView.After that is done..coming back to RosterViewController.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Cancel button presed");
}
else
{
    if(chatView)  // Chat ViewController
    {
        [chatView recvdMsg:self.messageDictionary];
    }
    else
    {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
         chatView=(ChatViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatviewcontroller"];

        NSMutableDictionary *buddy=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        // The break point stops the app here & shows buddy dictionary as nil.
 ==>    [buddy setObject:[self.messageDictionary objectForKey:@"sender"] forKey:@"jid"];

   // Originally it was messageContent dict from the parameter above that I used which worked fine..
  //But since I need that dictionary in another method..I copied that dictionary into self.messageDictionary which also gets copied.
  // However now the above line causes problems.


      //  [buddy setObject:[self.messageContent objectForKey:@"sender"] forKey:@"jid"];
        chatView.buddyData=buddy;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES];
        [chatView recvdMsg:self.messageDictionary];

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create `NSMutableDictionary` from `NSDictionary` you should use `dictionaryWithDictionary` which is declared in **`NSDictionary.h`**.

```
NSMutableDictionary *aMutDictFromAnotherDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:YOUR_NSDICTIONARY_OBJECT];
```

Comment: Tried your method , Still doesnt' work.the buddy dictionary sill shows  0 key/value pairs.

Comment: Yes.....actually both 'messageContent' and 'messageDictionary' show same content when I 'NSLog' them.

Comment: dont you want to copy contents of `messageContent` to `messageDictionary`? @icodes

Comment: [buddy setObject:[messageContent objectForKey:@"sender"] forKey:@"jid"];..this used to work.......but if I use self.messageDictionary instead of messageContent...after copying...it doesn't work.